# How can I pass URL parameters to redirect() with a named URL

Tags: django, django-views

I've written this:

```
return redirect('/cmmods/login?next=%2F')
```

which I want to be able to express like this

```
return redirect('login', next='%2F')
```

(or even better return `redirect('login', next='/')` )

But I can't see how to combine the URL parameter with the named URL.

This works:

```
return redirect('login')
```

so I know the named URL is OK - but I need to pass the 'next' parameter to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```

...

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login') + '?next=%2F')
```

the login [url](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/urls.py#L10) doesn't have a parameter next, but you can create a new url with next parameter and inject before the default django.contrib.auth one

```
 url(r'^login\?next=(?P<next>.*)$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login'),
```

and use that one instead if you prefer with `redirect('login', next='/')`